# Fix a minor typo on "The Stack Exchange Model" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, help-center

On [The Stack Exchange Model](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page, there is a minor typo near the end of the page:

> Votes on Meta Stack Overflow directly affect your reputation on Meta
> Stack Overflow only; **it they do not** affect your reputation on
> Stack Overflow or any other Stack Exchange site.
>
> [emphasis added]

The word "it" should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Laura fixed it, thanks!